# For loop inside another for loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a simple dynamic list which you can add other elements to and I want each time the client clicks on the circle, a class gets assigned to both the paragraph and the circle. I've tried making a for loop inside another for loop and it works, but it adds the class to all the paragraphs not only one.

[image: Here's the image of the list]

Here's the code I've tried

```
let circle = document.querySelectorAll(".circle"),
    paragraph = document.querySelectorAll(".paragraph");
for(i=0; i<circle.length; i++){
    circle[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        for(i=0; i<paragraph.length; i++){
            paragraph[i].classList.add('class')
        }
    })
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="dynamic" draggable="true">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <p class="paragraph"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your html also. I think you need to just check if the class does not exist already then only add.

Comment: I've added the HTML.

Comment: What's the point of the class `.class`? Because you can achieve styling with pure HTML+CSS. Also, if you need to add the same class on all sibling elements, you should instead add the class on the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could make sure your loop closes over `i` properly, then add the class to only `paragraph[i]` instead of to all paragraphs inside the loop:

```
const circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle"),
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll(".paragraph");
for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        paragraphs[i].classList.add('class');
    });
}
```

It looks like the paragraphs might be right next to the circles, in which case navigating to the `.nextElementSibling` of the clicked circle might work and'd be easier without two separate collections to worry about:

```
const circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle"),
for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        circles[i].nextElementSibling.classList.add('class');
    });
}
```